# Show that the image of the function $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x+\frac1x$ is the interval $[2,\infty)$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

- Show that the image of the function $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x+\dfrac{1}{x}$ is the interval $[2,\infty)$.

If $x=1$, then $f(1)=2$. So how can I show that the mage of the function is the interval $[2,\infty)$?

Comment: Solve the equation $x+\frac 1x=y$ whenever $y\ge2$?

Comment: Check if it is increasing decreasing in general extreme values

Comment: Hint: use AM-GM inequality or simply complete the square

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Clearly, it is not the same

Comment: @José Carlos Santos Clearly, it is not the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since for positive $x$ by Am-Gm we have $$x+{1\over x}\geq 2$$ with equality iff $x=1$ we see that the range is $[2,\infty)$ since $f$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$. Note that here is continuation essentialy, without it the claim is not necessary true.

---

**Alternatively**, you can avoid continuity. You need to find out for which $y$  is $$x+{1\over x}=y$$ solvable, so when is $x^2-yx+1=0$ solvable. That is true iff it discriminat is nonegative, i.e. $$y^2-4\geq 0\implies (y-2)(y+2)\geq 0$$ Since clearly $y=x+{1\over x}>0$ we have $y-2\geq 0$ so the range is $[2,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks for answer and comments.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It is $$x+\frac{1}{x}\geq 2$$ and this is equivalent to $$(x-1)^2\geq 0$$ if $$x>0$$